# JMeter Configuration for Websocket Broadcast

Tags: node.js, jmeter

I have a Nodejs WebSocket application which 
1) Accept a connection
2) Sends a message  ( Say 'Start' ), and will be added to a broadcast room. 
The response is 'Added to broadcast room'
3) All connected clients will get broadcasted messages.

The program is working fine with multiple clients and all getting broadcasted messages.

I am facing difficulty in simulating the same in Jmeter.

I have added 
- WebSocket - Open Connection ( which opens a connection ) - Working fine
- WebSocket - Request-Response sampler (Sends 'Start' and getting 'Added to broadcast room' ) - working fine

But the connected clients not getting broadcasted message from the server. 
How to create something like  ws.onmessage = function(e) {} in jmeter.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a "Single Read Sampler" to read a message sent by the server; put it in a loop to keep reading.